# PHP/MySQL - calculate average of column, split over months of year on file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that allows me to pull the total COUNT of my ID column and break it up into monthly scores which are then displayed into a table. Now, I would like to do the same thing for my 'OSAT' column, but instead of a COUNT, would need an AVERAGE. How do I go about this? I am a MySQL noob and could really use some help here please since just replacing COUNT with AVG in MySQL is not doing the trick...

Some more info on what this here actually is:
I have a table with guest reviews for restaurants. The records are filtered by

Date (the table displays months from Jan to Dec, hence I only filter out the year)
Property (column 'Holidex' which is a unique 5 digit code for the building the restaurant is in. One property can have multiple outlets.)
Outlet (the restaurant name)

The reviewer can score the experience at the restaurant on a scale from 1 to 5 and now I am trying to do some analytics. I already managed to do a total count of feedbacks for each month, but now would like to know the average scores for each month for items such as Food Quality, Beverage Selection, etc.

What I have so far:
Query:

```
    <table class="fb_feedback_results">
        <?php

        // multiple criteria selection
        $whereParts = array();
        if ($property) {
            $whereParts[] = "Holidex = '$property' ";
        } 

        if ($outlet) {
            $whereParts[] = "Outlet = '$outlet' ";
        } 

        if ($pickyear) {
            $whereParts[] = "YEAR(date) = '$pickyear' ";
        } 

        $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS MCOUNT FROM FB_Feedback_Card_Data");

        //BUILD THE FINAL QUERY
        if (count($whereParts) > 0) {
            $sql .= " WHERE " . implode('AND ', $whereParts);
        } 
        //count($whereParts) > 0

        $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die('<p>Query to get total data from FB_Feedback_Card_Data table failed:' . mysql_error() . '</p>');

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
        {
            $mcount = $row[0];
            $mydata = stats("ALLMYRECORDS", "ALLMYRECORDS", "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
        ?>

        <tr>
            <th class="header">Item</th>
            <th class="header">Jan</th>
            <th class="header">Feb</th>
            <th class="header">Mar</th>
            <th class="header">Apr</th>
            <th class="header">May</th>
            <th class="header">Jun</th>
            <th class="header">Jul</th>
            <th class="header">Aug</th>
            <th class="header">Sep</th>
            <th class="header">Oct</th>
            <th class="header">Nov</th>
            <th class="header">Dec</th>
            <th class="header">YTD</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="result_desc">Ttl. No. of Feedback</td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['a'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['b'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['c'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['d'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['e'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['f'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['g'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['h'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['i'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['j'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['k'];?></td>
            <td class="result"><?echo $mydata['l'];?></td>
            <td class="result_ytd"><strong><?echo $mydata['total'];?></strong></td>
        </tr>
            <?php
            // end grand total stats
            } 
            ?>
    </table>
```

Stats() function:

```
function stats($myfieldname, $myvalue, $property, $outlet, $pickyear,$mysqli)
{

//$mysqli=db_connect();

$whereParts = array();

if ($property) {
        $whereParts[] = "property = '$property' ";
} 
//$property

if ($outlet) {
        $whereParts[] = "outlet = '$outlet' ";
}
// outlet

if ($pickyear) {
        $whereParts[] = "YEAR(date) = '$pickyear' ";
} 
//$pickyear

    if ($myfieldname == "ALLMYRECORDS") {
        $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(id) AS mcount, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT month(date) ORDER BY month(date)) AS month_list FROM FB_Feedback_Card_Data");
        if (count($whereParts) > 0) {
            $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $whereParts);
        } //count($whereParts) > 0
    } 
//$myfieldname == "ALLMYRECORDS"

    else 
{
        $sql = ("SELECT DISTINCT " . "$myfieldname" . ", COUNT(id) AS mcount, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT month(date) 
        ORDER BY month(date)) AS month_list
        FROM FB_Feedback_Card_Data
        where " . "$myfieldname" . "=" . "'$myvalue'");

       if (count($whereParts) > 0) {
            $sql .= " AND " . implode(' AND ', $whereParts);
        } 
       //count($whereParts) > 0

       $sql .= " group by " . "$myfieldname" . " ORDER BY " . "$myfieldname";
    }

    $monthresult = $mysqli->query($sql) or die('<p>Query in stats to get data from FB_Feedback_Card_Data table failed:' . mysql_error() . '</p>');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($monthresult)) {
        if ($myfieldname == "ALLMYRECORDS") {
            $fieldname   = "ALLMYRECORDS";
            $totalcounts = $row[0];
            $months      = $row[1];
        } 
        //$myfieldname == "ALLMYRECORDS"

         else 
         {
            $fieldname   = $row[0];
            $totalcounts = $row[1];
            $months      = $row[2];
        }

        $countdata = explode(",", $months);
        $size      = sizeof($countdata);

        for ($m = 0; $m < 13; $m++) {
            if ($countdata[$m] == 1) {
                $y1 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 2) {
                $y2 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 3) {
                $y3 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 4) {
                $y4 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 5) {
                $y5 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 6) {
                $y6 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 7) {
                $y7 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 8) {
                $y8 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 9) {
                $y9 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 10) {
                $y10 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } //$countdata[$m] == 10

            if ($countdata[$m] == 11) {
                $y11 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            if ($countdata[$m] == 12) {
                $y12 = countrecords("$myfieldname", $fieldname, $countdata[$m], "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);
            } 

            // end for
        } 
        //$m = 0; $m < 13; $m++

        // end while
    } 
    //$row = mysqli_fetch_row($monthresult)

    $out['a']     = "$y1";
    $out['b']     = "$y2";
    $out['c']     = "$y3";
    $out['d']     = "$y4";
    $out['e']     = "$y5";
    $out['f']     = "$y6";
    $out['g']     = "$y7";
    $out['h']     = "$y8";
    $out['i']     = "$y9";
    $out['j']     = "$y10";
    $out['k']     = "$y11";
    $out['l']     = "$y12";
    $out['total'] = $totalcounts;

    return $out;
//end function
}
```

Comment: Can u add your query also so it becomes easy to help you

Comment: using AVG should work. Take a look: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-avg-function.htm

Comment: Do group by month(date) also

Comment: @Arjun the query for the count is SELECT COUNT(ID) AS MCOUNT FROM FB_Feedback_Card_Data as shown above, however, all the breaking down into months is done by the Stats() function.

Comment: @Erick looks simple enough, but I cannot group it by month like that. when I replace the COUNT with AVG in my function above, I receive an error though.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Armi : you need to group by month(date) if u want data to be calculated month wise

Comment: @Arjun, as matter of fact, I do that already via the function stats(). This is where I break everything apart. Check out the query in the second paragraph: "SELECT DISTINCT " . "$myfieldname" . ", COUNT(id) AS mcount, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT month(date) 
        ORDER BY month(date)) AS month_list
        FROM FB_Feedback_Card_Data
        where " . "$myfieldname" . "=" . "'$myvalue'");

Comment: Again, my problem here is that I dont know how to adjust the stats function to reflect AVG instead of COUNT. Any suggestions on this?